# Animate UILabel dimension before position

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uilabel, frame

I'm trying to animate two UIView together (an UIImageView and a UILabel) in three step: 
0) both views are in the top left corner of the screen 
1) then I change the frames (and for label the font size, too) so the views became bigger and on the center 
2) I change again the frames (and for label the font size, too) to put both views on the botton right corner. (this aniamtion starts after some seconds)
3) I remove both views from superview.

The UIImageView is perfect after every animation. For UILabel, first animation works, second one doesn't !
After first animation my label immidiately became smaller and after the delay it moves like the image view. I don't know why! I use "setFrame" to change together origin and size..

My code is:

```
@implementation Animazione
{
  UIImageView * imageView;
  UILabel * message;
}
-(void) startAnimationOn: (UIView *) superView;
{
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"..."];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [superView imageView];
    CGRect startRect = [self startDimension]; //make a CGRect
    [imageView setFrame:startRect];


    message = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    message.text = @"A text";
    message.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    message.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    [self setLabelSize: startRect];

    [message setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; 

    [superView addSubview:message];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                          delay:3.0
                        options:(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState)
                     animations:^{
                         [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
                         [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(hideViews:finished:context:)];

                         CGRect big = [self bigDimension];
                         [imageViews setFrame:big];
                         //  [self setLabelSize:big];
                         [message setFrame:big];

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"grande");

                     }];

}


  -(void) hideViews:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
 {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                          delay:5.0
                        options:(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations:^{

                         [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
                         [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(deliteViews:finished:context:)];

                         CGRect finally = [self finallyDimension];
                         [imageView setFrame:finally];
                       //  [self setLabelSize:finally];
                         [message setFrame:finally];

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"scomparso");
                     }];

}
}

-(void) deliteViews:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
    [message removeFromSuperview];
    imageView = nil;
    message = nil;
}

}

- (void)setLabelSize: (CGRect) originalDim
{
[message setFrame: originalDim];
message.font = [message.font fontWithSize:originalDim.size.height/8+10];
}
```

**Edit:**

Actually I have not explained well what I expect from animations and what they do instead.
For the first animation, I expect: 
- nothing for 3 second (the delay) 
- imageview and label grow and move at the same time (duration 2 second)
And it happens.

For the first animation, I expect: 
- nothing for 5 second (the delay) 
- imageview and label become smaller and move at the same time (duration 3 second)
What really happens:  
- *immediately the label change dimensions* 
- nothing for 5 second 
- imageview becomes smaller and move, label move

Comment: not related, but my eyes cry due do all of that `try/catch` dance your are doing. If you want to catch every uncaught exception for logging purposes, just set an exception handler with `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`

Comment: When you say 'the first animation works but the second one doesn't' it isn't clear what you mean. Give more detail regarding exactly what happens (or doesn't).

Comment: Thank you very much @Gabriele !!! I edit my question, I hope it is clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try 1:**
Try to set those settings to your label :

```
[label setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
[label setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
```

It will avoid it to be compressed by the frame (but not being made bigger).

**Try 2:**

Try to use UITextView rather than UILabel, could be better cause UITextView use a contentView that maybe won't be resized immediatly.

Comment: I try it, but the behavior is the same :(

Comment: Try to use UITextView rather than UILabel, could be better cause UITextView use a contentView that maybe won't be resized immediatly.

Comment: In fact, I already did (I edited this answer ;) )
I'm glad it works :D